# Postgres, where in on a json object

Tags: postgresql

I've been looking around and can't seem to find anything that is helping me understand how I can achieve the following. (Bear in mind I have simplified this to the problem I'm having and I am only storing simple JSON objects in this field)

Given I have a table "test" defined

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id int primary key
,   features jsonb
)
```

And some test data

| id | features |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"country": "Sweden"} |
| 2 | {"country": "Denmark"} |
| 3 | {"country": "Norway"} |

I've been trying to filter on the JSONB column "features". I can do this easily with one value

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE features @> '{"country": "Sweden"}'
```

But I've been having troubles working out how I could filter by multiple values succintly. I can do this

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE features @> '{"country": "Sweden"}'
OR features @> '{"country": "Norway"}'
```

But I have been wondering if there would be an equivalent to `WHERE IN ($1, $2, ...)` for JSONB columns.

I suspect that I will likely need to stick with the `WHERE... OR...` but would like to know if there is another way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jsonb->>'field_name'` extract a field as text, then you use any operator compatible with text type

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE features->>'country' = 'Sweden'

SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE features->>'country' in ('Sweden', 'Norway')
```

You an also directly work with jsonb as follow

`jsonb->'field_name'` extract field as jsonb, then you can use operator compatible with jsonb:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE features->'country' ?| array['Sweden', 'Norway']
```

See [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the country value, then you can use a regular IN condition:

```
select *
from test
where features ->> 'country' in ('Sweden', 'Norway')
```